# Enemy movement to only follow player when in range using navmesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new at C# (around 1 week in), so I have been following a lot of tutorials. I am at the moment trying to edit a piece of code (unity tutorial) to only have the enemy follow the player when in a certain range of the player  (10 foot), but unfortunately without changing the code completely, I cannot find a solution. At the moment the enemy will only follow the player when the player is alive (which i also want).

I've tried googling what I want, but I don't want to change the code from what is it too much. I am very new at c# and and currently learning bit by bit, other methods I have found require me changing the code a lot. As far as I understand, the main focus of the code below is for the enemy to be completely controlled by the Nav Mesh Agent, is it possible for me to keep the same technique?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Transform player;
    PlayerHealth playerHealth;
    EnemyHealth enemyHealth;
    UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent nav;

    void Awake()
    {
        // references
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        playerHealth = player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
        enemyHealth = GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
        nav = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0 && playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
        {
            nav.SetDestination(player.position);
            transform.LookAt(player);
        }
        else
        {
            nav.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

If possible, I would like to add 2 if functions. 1 being the check if the player is alive, and the other to check if the player is within distance. I don't know much about raycast at the moment, so will this be the next step for me to learn to get this to work how i want?

Thankyou for your time.
Dean.

Comment: you can calculate distance by doing `float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position,transform.position);`, do a check if it's no larger than some `amount` with `bool playerIsCloseEnough = distance <= amount;` and you can check if the player is alive with `bool playerIsAlive = playerHealth.currentHealth > 0;`. Then you can do things if they're both true with `if (playerIsAlive && playerIsCloseEnough) {...}`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, worked exactly how I wanted it to. I also had to set `nav.enabled=true;` within void awake for it to work with the nav mesh, for some reason it was disabling on startup. I also added `enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0 &&` to `if (playerIsAlive && playerIsCloseEnough) {...}` to stop the enemy from moving after it was dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate distance by doing:

```
float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position,transform.position);
```

You can do a check if it's no larger than some amount with:

```
bool playerIsCloseEnough = distance <= amount;
```

And you can check if the player is alive with:

```
 bool playerIsAlive = playerHealth.currentHealth > 0;
```

Then, you can do things if they're both true with:

```
if (playerIsAlive && playerIsCloseEnough) 
{
    // ...
}
```

And as you mentioned in the comment, you'll need to set `nav.enabled=true;` in `void Awake` or `void Start` to make sure the nav mesh is turned on :)

Comment: You've been a great help Ruzihm, I've got the enemy movement working exactly how i want it for now :)